# In Scrabble, does a blank tile on the double/triple word square count?

Tags: scrabble, scoring

If the blank tile is on a triple word tile while you are making a word, does it still count as a triple word?

Comment: @ava, a blank tile still scores 0, even on a DW or TW square.

Comment: @ava - from the same official rules quoted in my answer, rule number 1 "Use a score pad or piece of paper to keep a tally of each player's score, entering it after each turn. The score value of each letter is indicated by a number at the bottom of the tile. The score value of a blank is zero." It's not a 1 point tile.

Comment: The key strategic point is that while a blank gets zero points *directly*, it can be used to enable getting many points *indirectly*, by creating a longer word that hits a double or triple, by enabling use of a high-point letter (J,K,Q,X,Z) or by helping to create a Bingo (+50).

Answer (score 17):

Yes. It doesn't matter which tile is on the double/triple word space, if you make a word while placing a blank tile on one of these squares, your word score is still doubled/tripled. From the [official rules of Scrabble](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules):

> 4. Premium Word Squares: The score for an entire word is doubled when one of its letters is placed on a pink square: it is tripled when one of its letters is placed on a red square. Include premiums for double or triple letter values, if any, before doubling or tripling the word score. If a word is formed that covers two premium word squares, the score is doubled and then re-doubled (4 times the letter count), or tripled and then re-tripled (9 times the letter count). NOTE: the center square is a pink square, which doubles the score for the first word.
> 5. Letter and word premiums count only on the turn in which they are played. On later turns, letters already played on premium squares count at face value.
> 6. When a blank tile is played on a pink or red square, the value of the word is doubled or tripled, even though the blank itself has no score value.

Technically even on a double/triple letter score, the value of that blank tile is still doubled/tripled as well, however since the value of the tile is 0, doubling or tripling it does nothing.